# Who is Armilus?

Tags: messiah

We are told (Ben Ish Chai year 2 miketz, and others...) that Mashiach ben Yosef will fall in the hands of *Armilus HaRasha*. Some poskim (see ילקוט יוסף תפילה ב הערות נוסחאות התפלה והברכות) who even say we need to pray in our Amidah that MBY will not die at the hands of Armilus. I even saw in a footnote (of מושגים תלמודיים גוג ומגוג) that Gog is Armilus.

Do we know anything else about this seemingly important (albeit evil) character? *Please* bring sources!

Comment: he is mentioned on Is. 11:14 in the targum, pretty early source, though it could be a later addition to Yb"U's work

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article about Armilus. One must remember that there is no mention of Armilus until Saadia Gaon. This brings some doubt as to whether or not Armilus actually exists or whether it is just Christian philisophical influence

http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1789-armilus

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  This answer could be greatly improved by summarizing, in your own words, the key points of the article.

Comment: Ok my bad, ill do that in the future!

Comment: @ejLev, no need to wait for the future, you can [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/40468/edit) this answer as well.

Comment: great link. the armilus story mentioned is brought in the midrash talpios first book page 128. (Not an ancient medrash, seems to be 16th century or so). Just in case someone wants to read it inside, figured i'd mention where to find it in 'regular books'. Its still strange to read about moshiach's arch nemisis being reffered to as anticrist. And its entertaining to read it in hebrew once they interpolated nikudos and pronounced it anteekarshto.

Comment: Armilus is mentioned in the targum on Is. 11:4. this could be a later addition, but this individual found his way into the writings of Yb"U, at least tentatively!

Comment: @user6591 Note that Midrash Talpiyot is generally assumed to be Sabbatian. I don't know if any scholars think is isn't.

Comment: But who is he? This doesn't really tell us anything about who he is, and seems like a link only answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh I've read that flimsy accusation. It might even be true that the author was a sabbatean. Doesn't mean this work was 'a sabbatean work'. It has been accepted in all yeshivos. It's all good.

Comment: @user6591 OK. You are free to believe you want. I just thought you might want to know the issues surrounding the work.

Comment: @mevaqesh thank you. I try not to write off anyone no matter the accusations of their hashkafos. You know like Rambam being an Aristotilian philosopher and the like:)